How should I attach drywall at an inside corner without backing?
I have a basement bathroom whose toilet supply line corroded to failure, so I had to remove the whole thing and the drywall in front of it.  Unfortunately, there is only about 3.5" between the studs, and a ~1/2" gap where the old drywall was between one stud and the perpendicular drywall.
What's the best way to approach repairing this?  Should I try to attach two more studs between these existing ones for the new drywall (tricky given the tight space)?  Maybe just use 1x3s instead of full 2x4s?  Should I tear out more drywall to the next stud on the left, and then attach another one there (for new drywall about 19.5" wide)?




The 1/2" into the corner can overhang.
Cut the existing drywall back to the middle of a stud.
(Cut it level with the side of the stud then trim it back a bit more.)
Alternatively, fix a joining board to the back of the existing drywall and then fix the new drywall to that. (The joining board can be more drywall attached with screws and drywall adhesive.)

Depending what the framing looks like when you cut back the left drywall, it may be worth adding some blocking/framing to fasten the new piece of drywall to.

I wouldn't overhang that much with a sheet that wasn't attached to at least two studs. A sheet joining on just one is a hinge and won't be nearly as stout.
